# can Selector be used on class attributes in robot Browser lib

Tags: browser, robotframework, playwright

We need to automate a existing Web page. Unfortunately there are only a few Id's maintained.
The developers introduced a further attribute in the class, for there automation.

data-at...

In Browser I inspect the button and and getting this element:

```
<div _ngcontent-vvw-c276="" data-at-example="" class="title"> example </div>
```

the css path would be `#gtm_go-to > div`
In Robot Browser Library I can use the keyword `Browser.Click      \#gtm_go-to > div`
that works fine.
Is there a possibility to "Click based on the attribute information?
`Browser.Click      data-at-example=""`

Or is there a reverse keyword for `Get Element Attribute` -> `Get Path from Attribute`

Comment: Of Course maintain the ID: field would be the best solution. But the integration is not designed like that at the moment :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPATH locator could be used here.

1. To find a Div element with the attribute `data-at-example` of any value, the XPATH locator could look like this:

```
//div[@data-at-example]
```

2. Or with the additional condition of empty value:

`//div[@data-at-example=""]`